# RStudio Session Failing to restart or terminate

Tags: r, rstudio

Everytime I run a pice of code in RStudio, the R session stops working. Terminating the session or restarting it doesn't work. The session keeps getting frozen when I try to run any Chunk or piece of code for no apparent reason.

**Note**: This post is not related to RAM usage, size of vectors or unclean workspace. It's about when RStudio stops running properly the sessions whithout any apparent reason. If anyone knows why this happens please comment.

Comment: Make sure that you do not save your session since if you do, whatever is calling the problem is reloading. Also try doing a proper exit.

Comment: Tried it and didn´t work, apparently it was a problem with the files from R. Solution 3 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

These are some posible solutions to the issue in order of how "difficult" they are.

#### **Solution 1**

**Step 1**: press win + r

**Step 2**: type %AppData%

**Step 3**: C:\Users\ [username]\AppData\Roaming will open, look for Rstudio and delete it (or change the name if you want a backup)

**Step 4:** Run RStudio and try running any code to see if it's working.

#### **Solution 2**

**Step 1:** press win + r

**Step 2:** type %AppData%

**Step 3:** C:\Users\ [username]\AppData\Roaming will open, back up to C:\Users\ [username]\AppData and look for a folder called "Local"

**Step 4**: Once you find the folder, open it and search for a folder called RStudio-Desktop.

**Step 5**: Locate the folder and delete it (or change the name if you want the back up)

**Step 6**: Run RStudio and try running any code to see if it's working.

#### **Solution 3**

This is the one that worked for me.

**Step 1**: Deleting the folder called 'R' in C:\Users\ [username]\Documents\R and the .Rdata file found in 'Documents'

**Step 2**: Uninstall Rstudio AND R.

**Step 3**: Reinstall both R and Rstudio.

**Step 4**: Run RStudio and try running any code to see if it's working.